# Socket automatically closed?

Tags: sockets, winsock, tcp

I work on a network server on Windows that handles many requests per minute for days and days at thousands of customer sites.  But one particular customer has an issue where it appears a socket is getting reused before it's being closed.  These are normal run of the mill sockets as used in a webserver -- nothing unusual.

It's conceivable a client drops the connection.  But that shouldn't cause the socket to get reused until the socket is closed first, right?

Is there any circumstance that a socket could get reused without first getting closed?

Answer (score 0):

`socket()` cannot return a `SOCKET` value that was returned by a previous `socket()` call until it has to be closed first, such as with `closesocket()`.